# How to find which android branch/release is my device running?

Tags: android, android-version

I know that my device is running Android Kitkat 4.4.4.

I would like to know if there is anyway to figure out via adb or other means, which branch or release of Kitkat is it running. Ex. whether it is running 4.4.4_r1 or 4.4.4_r2?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
adb shell getprop | grep "ro.build"
```

optionally (without `| grep ...`). Maybe there will be the info you're looking for.